# Generate short, unique identifiers

Tags: c#, .net, guid, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I'm looking for an algorithm which generates identifiers suitable for both, external use in e.g. URLs as well as persistence with the following requirements:

- **Short**, like a max. of 8 characters
- **URL-friendly**, so no special characters
- **Human-friendly**, e.g. no ambigous characters like L/l, 0/O
- **Incremental** for fast indexing
- **Random**  to prevent guessing without knowing the algorithm (would be nice, but not important)
- **Unique** without requiring to check the database

I looked at various solutions, but all I found have some major tradeoffs. For example:

- GUID: Too long, not incremental
- GUID base64 encoded: Still too long, not incremental
- GUID ascii85 encoded: Short, not incremental, too many unsuitable characters
- GUID encodings like base32, base36: Short, but loss of information
- Comb GUID: Too long, however incremental
- All others based on random: Require checking the DB for uniqueness
- Time-based: Prone to collisions in clustered or multi-threaded environments

---

**Edit**: Why has this been marked off-topic? The requirements describe a specific problem to which numerous legitimate solutions can be provided. In fact, some of the solutions here are so good, I'm struggling with choosing the one to mark as answer.

Comment: they can't be both random and incremental by definition!!

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes, this is why I mentioned that randomness is not so important

Comment: Also: "All others based on random: Require checking the DB for uniqueness" : if it's long then you can reduce collisions (think GUID); if it's short then you MUST check a DB if you require uniqueness. You have too many conflicting requirements.

Comment: Short, unique, random - pick any two.

Comment: Agree with @MitchWheat, you have too many conflicting requirements.  Considering you have all the requirements in place is there any reason why you can't implement this yourself?  Are you wanting a solution or suggestions?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you are looking for a URL shortener solution. I don't quite understand the 2nd function of persistence though. What sort of scenario you need to have persistence, but do not want to hit the database?

Comment: @500InternalServerError: Sad truth, it seems. :)

Comment: @Brad: The requirements are not meant to be conflicting. (The only one being randomness, that's why I wrote 'not important'). A comb GUID for instance would be perfect and satisfies all requirements, however it's simply too long. I'm basically looking for an algorithm which is shorter than 128 bits and unique, but not required to be 'globally' unique. :)

Comment: @alextansc Kind of. URL shortener algorithms are not meant to produce unique results as they are already based on an unique value (the URL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If at all possible I'd keep the user requirements (short, readable) and the database requirements (incremental, fast indexing) separate. User-facing requirements change. You don't want to have to modify your tables because tomorrow you decide to change the length or other specifics of your user-facing ID.

One approach is to generate your ID using user-friendly characters, like
`23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ` and just make it random.

But when inserting into the database, don't make that value the primary key for the record it references or even store it in that table. Insert it into its own table with an identity primary key, and then store that `int` or `bigint` key with your record.

That way your primary table can have an incremental primary key. If you need to reference a record by its "friendly" ID then you join to your friendly ID table.

My guess is that if you're generating a high enough volume of these IDs that you're concerned about index performance then the rate at which human users retrieve those values will be much lower. So the slightly slower lookup of the random value in the friendly ID table won't be a problem.

Comment: Accepted because that's actually not a bad idea. It might seem redundant to have two identifiers, but you're right, essentially the requirements reflect two different concerns. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following uses a combination of an ID that is known to be unique (because it comes from a unique ID column in a relational database) and a random sequence of letters and numbers to generate a token:

```
public static string GenerateAccessToken(string uniqueId) // generates a unique, random, and alphanumeric token
{
    const string availableChars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    using (var generator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[16];
        generator.GetBytes(bytes);
        var chars = bytes.Select(b => availableChars[b % availableChars.Length]);
        var token = new string(chars.ToArray());
        return uniqueId + token;
    }
}
```

The token is guaranteed to be both unique and random (or at least "pseudo random"). You can manipulate the length by changing the length of `bytes`.

To avoid confusion between "0" and "O" or "l" and "1", you can remove those characters from `availableChars`.

---

**Edit**

I just realized this doesn't quite pass the "no database check" requirement, though when I've used code like this, I've always already had an entity in memory that I knew contained a unique ID, so I'm hoping the same applies to your situation. I don't think it's possible to quite achieve all your requirements, so I'm hoping this would still be a good balance of attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried **proquints**?

A Proquint is a PRO-nouncable QUINT-uplet of alternating unambiguous consonants and vowels, for example: "lusab".

I think they meet almost all your requirements.

See the proposal [here](http://arxiv.org/html/0901.4016).
And [here](https://github.com/dsw/proquint) is the official implementation in C and Java.

I've worked on a port to .NET that you can download as [Proquint.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Proquint.NET).

Comment: I like that. The ID itself isn't user-friendly, but it can be translated to and from a user-friendly representation.

Comment: Do you have to worry that at some point it's going to generate something that sounds offensive?

Comment: @ScottHannen Ouch: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator

Comment: ["bosom","bum","fuk","gonad","guro","hobag","homo","kafir","kum","mofo","moron","nazi","pubis","sodom","tit","titi","vagin","vomit"] these are the few words which could appear in the result. This few words is from [~1700 bad words here](https://www.freewebheaders.com/full-list-of-bad-words-banned-by-google/) filtered by length <= 5 and correct CV combinations. There could be other possibilities too

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I implemented before does not fulfill all of your constraints but might be acceptable if you think about your problem a little bit differently.

First, I used a function to obfusticate the database id `func(id) => y`, and `func(y) => id`. (I used a [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt) is an example of implementing of such a function) Second, convert the obfusticated id to base 62 so it becomes short and url-friendly. (You can use a smaller character set to achieve Human-friendly) This creates a one-to-one mapping from database id to string identifiers. In my implementation, 1, 2 maps to 2PawdM, 5eeGE8 correspondingly, and I can get the database id 1, 2 back from the string 2PawdM and 5eeGE8. The mapping could be entirely different when you use a different obfustication function.

With this solution, the identifiers themselves **are NOT incremental**, however, because the identifiers maps directly to database id, you can compute the corresponding database id and directly do any database queries on id column instead. You don't need to generate a string identifier and store it to database, and the uniqueness is guaranteed by database itself when you store the record with a auto-incremented id column.